# Elisione facoltativa o obbligatoria?

Tags: grammar

Ho letto, come già sapevo, che l'articolo determinativo "la", l'indeterminativo femminile "una" (anche derivati come alcuna, nessuna) e questo/questa hanno un'elisione facoltativa:

Questo uomo o quest'uomo.

Questa arancia o quest'arancia.

Credo valga anche per l'aggettivo bello.

https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/elisione_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/

Mentre per "quello" o "quella" non ho trovato alcuna informazione circa il fatto che sia obbligatoria l'elisione o meno.
La regola in questo preciso caso cosa dice?

Comment: La voce dell'enciclopedia Treccani che citi menziona anche “quello”, ma in effetti la questione merita di essere approfondita perché mentre “questo uomo” suona lievemente insolito ma non troppo, “quello uomo” è impossibile in italiano contemporaneo.

Answer (score 4):

[Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/quello_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/): "La scelta tra le varie forme del maschile singolare (quello, quell’ con ➔elisione e quel con ➔troncamento), del femminile singolare (quella e quell’) e del maschile plurale (quei e quegli) **segue le stesse regole che valgono per l’articolo ➔determinativo**; come per l’articolo determinativo, il femminile plurale ha un’unica forma, quelle."

Quindi,

- **Quello, quella: l'elisione è  obbligatoria -** quell'uomo*, quell'amica
- Quelle: l'elisione è impossibile

**Quello uomo*: un po' meno raro [in passato](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quell%27uomo%2Cquello+uomo&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=33&smoothing=5&case_insensitive=true).